# Horizontal Scroll Bar for JSF hx:dataTableEx component

Tags: css, jsf, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling, hxdatatableex

In my JSF application I need to have `hx:datatableEx` table component with horizontal scroll bar.

`Why it's required:`

1. Row text **must not wrap into next line.**(Must be displayed in single line).
2. If text in the row grows more than **table column size or table size,** then add a scroll bar to the table for rendering complete text instead of hiding overflown text.

Following Image describes the same problem.

[image: See datatable without horizontal scroll bar though row data occupying more than table width]

In picture you can see the vertical scroll bar because datatable height exceeds.

You can also see how text of the attribute Details column(Last column) is hiding when text is more than table or column width with no horizontal scroll bar to view the hidden text.

Please help me to get it done.

Thank you

Nagesh.N

Comment: Please give any alternative ways to view the complete datatable details.

Comment: @balusC please have a look on this query. I need solution it's urgent.